# Win IoT: Ethernet Config

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

Is there any way to reconfigure default Ethernet settings on Raspberry Pi 3 with Win 10 IoT? I managed to get it working with WiFi and it does connect with my PC over Ethernet cable, but still I would like static address possibly etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using PowerShell if you setup a remote management session to your device.

For example:

```
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter `
    -Name Ethernet

New-NetIPAddress `
    -InterfaceAlias $adapter.Name `
    -AddressFamily IPv4 `
    -IPAddress 192.168.1.55 `
    -PrefixLength 24 `
    -DefaultGateway 192.168.1.1; 

Set-DnsClientServerAddress `
    -InterfaceAlias $adapter.Name `
    -ServerAddresses ("192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3")
```

Comment: You can off course, place that code into a file called `makestatic.ps` and run that on your Pi once.